# How can I force iOS to redraw view after each change inside a loop

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, xcode5

I am trying to experiment with how fast I can make calls from Objective-C to JavaScript. So far I have the following code

```
- (IBAction)didTapUpdateWebView:(id)sender {
    int hits = 30;
    CFTimeInterval startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    NSLog(@"time before: %f", startTime);
    for (int i = 0; i < hits; i++) {
        NSString *str=[self.fNameTextField.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", i];
        NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setFirst('%@')", str];
        NSString *ret=[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
        NSLog(@"sent %@", ret);
        [self updateNativeNameValuesWithFirstName:str];

        // trying to refresh the view but none of these work
        [self.view.layer setNeedsDisplay];
        [self.view.layer setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutSubviews];
        [self.view.layer displayIfNeeded];

        // sleep for a bit so change is visible
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    }
    CFTimeInterval finishTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    float delta = finishTime - startTime;
    NSString *result =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"alert('%d hits took %f seconds')", hits, delta];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:result];
}
```

I want to see the UI get updated after each iteration of the loop. However, it seems that the loop gets executed in the background and there is no visible change until the loop is finished and the alert is discarded. How can I make sure that UI will be updated after each single iteration of the loop?

Comment: i dont see any use by sleeping the main thread unless javascript renderer runs in background.

Comment: I originally did not have the sleep in there and will take it out once I figure out the rendering issue. I put it there just to make sure I am not visually missing the rendering. Right now when I run the code I can see logs every 0.1 second, but I dont see any change in the UI until the whole thing is finished